# Missing module in beanstalk npm/yarn installation, only works as root

Tags: npm, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, yarnpkg

I have a posthook to install npm on my (PHP) beanstalk to build something programatically.

Here is the script from .platfom/hooks/postdeploy/99_node.sh

```
curl -fsSL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash -
yum install -y nodejs

npm install -g yarn lerna gatsby-cli
yarn global add lerna gatsby-cli
yarn start
```

The biggest problem is when I run `yarn build` (starting a Gatsby build) it does not work from the webapp user but only as root. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I presume the posthook will be running as the root user since you don't need a `sudo` or similar to execute the `yum install`. This means that you're also installing the packages as the root user. This is probably the reason why you're running into permission issues.

You should be able to use the `su` command to switch users (to the webapp user) after you've run the `yum install` in order to run the `npm install` as the correct user which should automatically fix the permissions/installation location problems that are probably the cause of this.